# 405 method not allowed - CodeIgniter Rest-server

Tags: php, http-headers, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-restserver

I am having troubles with Codeigniter - Rest Server for a week already.
I have a controller called **Users** with 2 methods **all_users_get** and **register_post**.

1. **all_users_get** is working fine.
2. **register_post**

   `returns { "status": false, "error": "Unknown method" }`

If I change the method **all_users_get** for POST I get the same error, just works with GET

```
<?php

use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';
require APPPATH . 'libraries/Format.php';

class Users extends REST_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    // Construct the parent class
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('user_model');

    // Configure limits on our controller methods
    // Ensure you have created the 'limits' table and enabled 'limits' within application/config/rest.php
    $this->methods['users_get']['limit'] = 500; // 500 requests per hour per user/key
    $this->methods['users_post']['limit'] = 100; // 100 requests per hour per user/key
    $this->methods['users_delete']['limit'] = 50; // 50 requests per hour per user/key
}

/**
 * @method: GET
 * Fetch all users
 */

public function all_users_get()
{
    $users = $this->user_model->all_users();
    // Check if the users data store contains users (in case the database result returns NULL)
    if ($users)
    {
        // Set the response and exit
        $this->response($users, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); // OK (200) being the HTTP response code
    }
    else
    {
        // Set the response and exit
        $this->response([
            'status' => FALSE,
            'message' => 'No users were found'
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND); // NOT_FOUND (404) being the HTTP response code
    }
    $this->response($users, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);

}

/**
 * User Register
 * *************************
 * 
 * @param: fullname
 * @param: email address
 * @param: password
 * @param: username
 * 
 * *************************
 * @method: POST
 * @link : api/users/register
 */

public function resgister_post()
{

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    $this->response("Teste", REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);

}

}
```

I am running my code in localhost with Xampp and I found on **phpinfo**

_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]   GET

I am confused I don't know if this had something to do with Xampp conf or my code, please help. Thank you all

Comment: Maybe a typo...in your code `resgister_post` should be `register_post` instead.

Comment: very well observed Hackerman, but unfortunately hasn't my typo the problem. :/

Comment: How are you calling the `register` endpoint? Can you add that code too?

Comment: Might want to check `CORS` settings inside of the `rest.php` config file. reply @Hackerman question and further help may be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This function should work for you :)

```
  public function index_post()// post data to the database
  {
    $data = [
        'first_name'        => $this->post('first_name'),
        'last_name'         => $this->post('last_name'),
        'email'             => $this->post('email')

    ];

    if( $this->users->createUser($data) > 0)
    {
        $this->response([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'NEW USER CREATED'
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED); 
    }
    else{
        $this->response([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => 'FAILED TO CREATE NEW USER'
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
    exit;
}
```

just copy above line in constructor it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**Ultimate Solution**
**Step 1**
In your constructor, add the code below

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
    die();
}
```

**Step 2:**
Open your route.php and define an API route
e.g

```
$route['api/v1/auth/login'] = 'api/v1/auth/login';
```

**Note:** the route will be used in step 3

**Step 3:**
Open your config.php, add the code below

```
if (stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/api/v1/auth/login/') === FALSE) {
    $config['csrf_protection']  = FALSE;
}else{ 
    $config['csrf_protection']  = FALSE; 
}
```

Note: change `/api/v1/auth/login/` to your endpoint